# Style attribute of HTML fieldSet Tag is Not Working

Tags: html, css

My HTML is look like these

```
<html>
<body>
<fieldSet id="sourceName" style="width: 350px; height: 80px; overflow: auto;">
Some Data.....
</fieldSet>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is working fine in IE and Opera but when i run the same code in mozilla Firefox the style attribute of fieldSet is not working on mozilla what should i use. my simple Qustion is how to give scrollbar to fieldSet in mozilla.

Comment: Is any of the style working?  Experiment with firebug enabling and disabling CSS elements and tell us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FF doesn't seem to handle fieldset overflow in a standard way. As a workaround, use a nested div:

```
<fieldSet id="sourceName" style="width: 350px; height: 80px;">
    <div style="width: 350px; height: 80px; overflow: auto;">
        Some Data.....
    </div>
</fieldSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `overflow: scroll`, that should work.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem in FF.